# How to get desired response in res.send()?

Tags: node.js, express, response

What I am trying to do is fetch details from Db and while I get the response,the attributes name shouldn't be same as the Db so for that I am using for loop. WHile i try to console it I am getting desired response but I am getting empty array/the last data of the db. Can anyone help me out?

```
// ------display all customer group---->
const displayCustomerGroup = async (req,res,next) =>{
    var results = await Group.findAll();
    var newData ={};
    var data = {};
  
 for(var i = 0; i < results.length ; i++){

    for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(results[i].dataValues)){
        newData[key.replace("cg_","")] = value;  
    
    }
    
    console.log(newData)
  }
  res.json({
    status:"success",
    message:"Successfully",
    data:newData 
    })      

}
```

Comment: What DB client are you using?

Comment: i am using mysql db

Comment: `newData = {}` -- this is not an array.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.. I wanted the whole 'newData' in res.send() but I am getting only the last data.. @qqilihq

Comment: it's a MySQL DB, but what package are you using to connect to DB? Sequelize?

Comment: Yes sequelize....@GabrielMC

Comment: Are the keys unique accross all the dataValues objects? If you move console.log(newData) outside the for loop, does it still look correct?

Comment: Yes that is the exact problem. Inside loop it is giving correct response.I need some way to store it in some variable and use it in res.send() @Sully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have two loops: you have many results (which you iterate over in the outer loop), and each result has a set of many key-value pairs (which you iterate through in the inner loop). The inner loop is copying the key-value pairs into `newData`, but if the next result has the same key names, they will overwrite the previous result's data.

Instead, you need to use an array of objects, and fill that list item by item in the outer loop:

```
var dataList =[];

for(var i = 0; i < results.length ; i++){
    let dataItem = {};
    for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(results[i].dataValues)){
        dataItem[key.replace("cg_","")] = value;
    }
    dataList.push(dataItem);
}
res.json({
    status:"success",
    message:"Successfully",
    data: dataList
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was stuck at this for so long. It worked!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Sequelize models, you can pass options to the `findAll()` method. The option you are looking for is the `attributes` option. This lets you choose which columns you want returned - similar to the SELECT statement in SQL. `Attributes` should be an array of strings that match the column names.

For example:

```
await Group.findAll({
     attributes: ["Id", "Name", "CreateDate"]
})
```

If you want, you can also rename the columns by passing an array of arrays, where each array has first, the name of the column, and second, the new name of the column:

```
await Group.findAll({
     attributes: [["cg_id","Id"], ["cg_name", "Name"], ["cg_date", "CreateDate"]]
})
```

In SQL, this would basically be this:

```
SELECT cg_id AS Id, cg_Name AS Name, cg_date AS CreateDate
FROM Group
```